# Symfony disabled options for EntityType

Tags: forms, symfony

Suppose I have an entity `competence` that is ManyToMany related to the entity `location`. Furthermore there are `users` that have access to only one location.

Now imagine the following scenario: Competence `FirstHelp` is related to locations `Berlin` and `Munich`. User `Bob` has access to location `Berlin`. `Bob` now wants to edit `FirstHelp`. He should be allowed to remove or add the relation between `FirstHelp` and `Berlin` but he should **not** be allowed to touch the relation `FirstHelp` <=> `Munich`. He should *also* not be allowed to add other relations like `FirstHelp` <=> `Cologne`.

So far I have a `CompetenceType` with an EntityType field:

```php
class CompetenceType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add(
                'locations',
                EntityType::class,
                [
                    'class' => Location::class,
                    'choice_label' => 'name',
                    'multiple' => true,
                    'expanded' => true,
                    'label' => "Locations",
                ]
            );
    }
}
```

How can I set up the form in such a way, that `Bob` cannot modify the `Munich` relation but **can** modify the `Berlin` relation?

I tried to disable the `Munich` option with the `choice_attr` callback, however this leads to always removing the `Munich` relation.

I also tried using the `query_builder` to fetch only the `Berlin` entity but just like the above solution this leads to always removing the `Munich` relation.

A third idea has been to set `by_reference` to `false` and then modifying the adders and removers appropriately. i couldn't use this solution because I don't have access to the container within the entity and thus cannot check, if `Bob` has the right to manipulate all relations instead of just the one of his own location.

Please note: I would like to have solution that doesn't involve the controller. I know I could simply re-add the `Munich` relation through the controller afterwards but this would be just a dirty hack. In my opinion it should be the sole responsibility of the form to handle this.

Answer (score 2):

I would say, just that one form can only carry you so far. However, ...

To somehow manage this not so easy task with the `EntityType` alone. To make the form carry all of it? `EntityType` is meant to handle a set of uniform things.

My approach would be to handle the entities (or links or whatever) discriminately: those that can be edited and those that can't be edited. I would use a [DataMapper](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_mappers.html), to **separate** the entities into those two groups, one can be set to be disabled (or be omitted entirely), and the other can be edited and stuff, whatever you need. On the reverse direction (`DataMapper::mapFormsToData`), you have to *somewhat* manage the collection properly to remove/add/edit relevant entities, but I believe you get the original entity by reference and it should work fine. However, I haven't ever done this ...

If you show the disabled entities, you can *probably* rely on the disabled form to deny any changes to the entities that should not be changed.

So, summarized:

- implement the [`DataMapperInterface`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/DataMapperInterface.php) on your form type
- in `mapDataToForms` you filter out the non/editable entities to one field to be edited
- in `mapFormsToData` you have to filter out the non/editable entities again, so that you can determine which entities to add/remove/edit

Hope this helps ... or at least provides an approach.

Comment: Very interesting idea! While I didn't actually use it (It would've meant to map all FormFields in this way) it gave me the right idea: Using the `FormEvents::SUBMIT`-Event to modify the incoming data accordingly.

Comment: i thought about form events, but I guess I didn't research enough to find out if the original object / collection could be retrieved this way ... but for all those you follow your lead, you could post your solution as well ;o)